# A sobolev function with zero differential is constant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$:

Suppose that $u \in W^{1,p}(U)$ satisfies $Du=0$ almost everywhere in $U$.

How to prove $u$ is constant a.e in $U$?

Comment: By $Du$, you mean the weak derivative of $u$, right?

Comment: Yes, this is a shorthand for saying $\partial u_1,...,\partial u_n$. (where the $u_i$ are the corresponding weak derivatives of $u$.

Comment: This basically says,that for all compactly supported smooth functions on $U$, we have $\int_U u\phi' = 0$. Is that correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: $\int_U u \frac{\partial{\phi}}{x_i}=0$ for all such $\phi$, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have to work with mollifiers $(\rho_\epsilon)_{\epsilon > 0}$, where we can start with $\epsilon$ sufficiently small for each point in $U$ so that the function is well defined.

It is known that as $\epsilon \to 0$, we have in $W^{1,p}$, that $u * \rho_\epsilon \to u$. Since $D(u * \rho_\epsilon) = Du * \rho_\epsilon = 0$, we have that $u * \rho_\epsilon$ is constant, since it is a smooth function with derivative $0$. Let this constant be $c_\epsilon$.

Hence, $u$ is the limit of constant functions, hence is also constant, since convergence in $W^{1,p}$ implies convergence in $L^p$, which implies convergence a.e.

It's worth noting that this  is true only if $\Omega$ is connected, otherwise the function could take different constants in different connected components.

Comment: Thanks. I think some more care should be taken regarding the fact $u * \rho_{\epsilon}$ are not defined on all $U$, but on $U_{\epsilon}=\{ x \in U \, |\, d(x,\partial U) > \epsilon\}$. I think we should take a countable cover of balls of $U$, $(U_i)_{i=1,2...}$. For each $U_i$, $u * \rho_{\epsilon}$ is defined on $U_i$ for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, hence your argument (the a.e convergence, restricted to $U_i$) shows that $u=c_i$ almost everywhere. But how do we know all the $c_i$ are the same? (even when assuming $\Omega$ is connected).

Comment: Suppose the covering sets are nested sets, then will this do the trick, so that two constants can't be different at a common  point.

Comment: @AsafShachar You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Since $D u = 0$, you have $u \in W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ for all $k \ge 1$. By Sobolev embedding, $u$ is smooth. Now, it is easy to check that $u$ is constant (in each connected component of $\Omega$).